# Bind C-, and C-

Tags: emacs

Is there anyway that we can bind `C-,` and `C-.` in emacs ? I have tried this `(define-key global-map (kbd "C-,") 'action)` but it doesn't seem to work.

I use Emacs on Ubuntu with US keyboard layout.

Thanks

Comment: Which platform, what keyboard layout? It might not be possible at all if you are using the console on a CP/M box or connecting to an OS/360 mainframe with Putty.

Comment: You haven't told us that you're running emacs in a console instead of using the GUI. That's probably why it won't work. The binding sticks, but the console won't send the key press through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty your `define-key` does work.

But most likely when you hit `C-,` Emacs doesn't actually receive this.

What does `C-h k C-,` tell you?  What about `C-, C-h l` ?

My crystal ball tells me you're running in a text-terminal of some sort.  In those beasts many key combos don't actually get through correctly to the running application.

Comment: yes, I do run emacs in terminal. yes, like you said, terminal doesn't receive the commands. hmm, it's a bit weird xD. I'm moving from Vim, I'm finding a good key combo to cycle around flycheck errors, I guess I would find another pair. I'm used to [-n ]-p. but binding begin with [ or ] doesn't seem to be allowed in emacs :)

Comment: Note that for most text-terminals (e.g. Linux's console, xterm) you can teach them to send an escape sequence of your choice for the keys you care about, and then you can teach Emacs to recognize those escape sequences.  And of course Emacs *does* let you `(global-set-key "[n" 'action)`.  You just need to `(global-unset-key "[")` first.

Answer (score 1):

You could try some [key binding commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html), e.g.

```
(global-set-key [(control ?,)] 'some-action)
```

in your `~/.emacs` file (to make your key binding permanent, and available after restart). BTW, you could evaluate that first to test it. Then restart your `emacs` and use <kbd>C-h k C-,</kbd> to check if it is bound.

Comment: Don't restart emacs, just evaluate `(global-set-key ...)` and then see if it's bound.

Comment: Yeah, but then you have to restart your emacs instance, which is painful. You just need to add the sexp to your `.emacs` or `init.el` and then evaluate. Then it'll be there later, but you don't lose the state of your text editor.